# Problem with plain pagestyle in twosided document with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage

I'm trying to use `scrlayer-scrpage` with a twosided document using the `scrartcl` class but somehow can't manage to format the `plain` pagestyle in a way that is similar to the `scrheadings` style. I prepared the following MWE – thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline,markcase=nouppercase]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\chead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\ihead{}
\ohead{}
\ifoot{}
\ofoot{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\section{Blah.}

Blah.

\newpage

\section{Blah.}

Blah.

\newpage

\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}


\section{Blah.}

Blah.

\newpage

\section{Blah.}

Blah.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` (note the asterisk) and do similar for the other instances.

Comment: A different question would be why you are using a plain pagestyle, when an article class generally use one. All the `\newpage` in your code are clues, that you should have used a `report` (or een book) class.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It seems as if the problem is created by my local tex destribution as it works when I try the starred commands on Overleaf. The \newpage commands were only for illustrative purposes btw :)

Comment: You might have an old (older than two years?) distribution, which an update could resolve.

Answer (score 4):

To format the `plain` pagestyle use the optional argument of `\cfoot` etc:

```
\cfoot[<settings for plain>]{<settings for scrheadings>}
```

If both arguments are equal, you can use the short starred version:

```
\cfoot*{<settings for plain and scrheadings>}
```

If the `plain` style should also use the lines, add `plainheadsepline` and/or `plainfootsepline` to the package options of `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass[12,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline,
  plainheadsepline,
  footsepline,
  plainfootsepline,
  markcase=nouppercase
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmarkformat}{}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\blinddocument

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Additional remarks:

- Option `automark` does the same as `\automark[subsection]{section}` if the class does not know chapters.
- If there should be the section in header on even pages and the subsection you can use `\chead{\headmark}`.
- To set the font of the page header use `\setkomafont{pagehead}{<font settings>}`.
- With package `scrlayer-scrpage` pagestyle `plain` is redefined as an alias for pagestyle `plain.scrheadings`.